# Return functions in Unity with Firebase Async Query

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get User Data in Firebase Firestore, so I pass the UID to the method and it Returns a string (which is my information, like my username). The problem is that the query of firebase is Async, and it results in returning before the query is completed.

How would I work to always return when the query is completed?

```
public string ReturnUserInfo(string _info, string _key)
    {
        string returnableValue = "";
        Query userQuery = DB.Collection("users").WhereEqualTo("userID", _key);
        userQuery.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            QuerySnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in snapshot.Documents)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> user = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in user)
                {
                    if (pair.Key == _info)
                        returnableValue = pair.Value.ToString();
                }
            };
        });

        return returnableValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly return something!

The task is executed **asynchronously** and you directly return `""` since your method immediately continues with the rest of the code while `ContinueWithOnMainThread` is executed way later when the task is finished.

You would need to rethink this a little and rather use e.g. a callback like

```
// pass in a callback to be executed when the information is successfully retrieved
public void ReturnUserInfo(string _info, string _key, Action<string> onSuccess)
{
    var userQuery = DB.Collection("users").WhereEqualTo("userID", _key);
    userQuery.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        var snapshot = task.Result;
        foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in snapshot.Documents)
        {
            var user = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary();

            // This is btw way better than iterating through the dictionary
            if(user.TryGetValue(_info, out var value))
            {
                // invoke the callback
                onSuccess?.Invoke(value.ToString());
                // since you are also probably looking for only one result 
                return;
            }
        };
    });
}
```

so instead of using e.g.

```
var result = ReturnUserInfo("xy", "zw");
```

you rather do

```
ReturnUserInfo("xy", "zw", result =>
{
    // use result here
});
```

or with a method instead of a lambda

```
ReturnUserInfo("xy", "zw", OnUserInfoReceived);

...

private void OnUserInfoReceived(string result)
{
    // use result here
}
```